# Iterating through Unique FileNames in DataGridView and Saving Data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm processing a some files and adding the result of each file to datagridview.
I use 2 separate Background workers to do this.

1-Used for Simply getting data and populate the DataGridView

2-Process the items in the DataGridView one by one and get results

Now i want to save the results of processing to separate files for each **Unique File Name** in DataGridView.

For this purpose i have added a user invisible column named **FileName** to the DatGridView by using `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtenstion()`

Each row in the DataGridView contains the filename and its associated data,i need a way to iterate through the rows and save the data to a file (Single File for each Unique FileName)..
How can i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Do any two file names have the same name in the same directory or are they hierarchically present but have the same name?

Comment: @SurajS Multiple Files with the same name from different directories can be added to the List of Files

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to skip files which are already processed and process only one filename once, but if I have understood your question correctly, something like this would do,

```
List<string> uniqueNames = new List<string>();           
              foreach(DataGridViewRow r in view.Rows)
              {
                  FileStream file;

                  if (!uniqueNames.Contains(r.Cells["FileName"].Value.ToString()))
                  {
                      file = File.OpenWrite("yourPath\\" + r.Cells["FileName"].Value.ToString());
                    byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(r.Cells["Data"].Value.ToString());

                      file.Write(array, 0,array.Length);
                      file.Close();
                      uniqueNames.Add(r.Cells["FileName"].Value.ToString());
                  }

              }
```

This maintains a list of all unique file names already processed, if the file name is not in the list, it creates a new file and writes it, then adds it to the list.

Comment: This is the real issue im facing .. please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126554/filter-items-in-datatable-based-on-filename-entry-and-save-as-separate-file

Comment: Question removed @techno

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   var data = row.Cells["Data"].Value.ToString();
   File.WriteAllText(row.Cells["FileName"].Value.ToString(), data);
   // You can use append if you don't want to lose existing contents.
   //File.AppendAllText(row.Cells["FileName"].Value.ToString(), data);
}
```

> File.WriteAllText will Create a new file, writes the specified string
>   to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already
>   exists, it is overwritten.